# Server-side(python) and client-side(javascript) design and interaction

Tags: javascript, python, web-applications, flask

I am building a web application with Python on Flask and javascript. YouTube Data API (python) and YouTube player API(javascript) are used.

Although I have developed a few web applications already, deciding whether some logic should work from the server or client is still quite vague to me. When I learn from this example, I would have a more solid understanding regarding this matter.

I am using Youtube Data API from the server in Python to retrieve the most related video to the user's search query.

**my_app.py** (on Flask)

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
  """finds the most relevant video's id using YouTube Data API"""
  search_param = request.args.get('video_search')
  video_id = search_video(search_param)
  return render_template("index.html", video_id=video_id)
```

**index.html**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{{ video_id }}?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The above works great. However, I want more control over the YouTube player. Instead of manually embeding the video like provided, I decide to use YouTube Player API in javascript.

**index.html with javascript**

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('iframe-player', { //inserts into 'iframe-player'
        width: '640',
        height: '390',
        //videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE', <<<<< PAY ATTENTION TO THIS PART
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady, //onPlayaerReady will fire when onReady executes
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange //onPlayerStateChange will fire when onStateChange executes
        }
    });
}
```

This is the relevant javascript code. I need to pass a video_id in order to use YouTube Player API in javascript. For the current logic to work, the flow should be like below:

1. user searches for a video
2. server: finds a video and returns `video_id`
3. client: using `video_id` returned from the server, loads the player and plays the video.

**First question:**
However, isn't it impossible to do that? Javascript functions are loaded before the server returns anything. It would be impossible to pass a value from a server method to a javascript function. Am I correct?

**Second question:**
In this case, is it better not to use Python at all and do everything from the client side using only javascript?

**Third question:**
Would this return error?

```
<div id="my_video_id">{{video_id}}</div>
<script>
  var video_id = $("#my_video_id")
</script>
```

Thank you. I tried my best to explain the problem. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the video id to the `index.html` template, so just use it inside your Javascript.

For example in the `index.html` template and inside a script tag holding your Javascript add the video id using `{{ video_id }}`:

```
<script>
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('iframe-player', {
        width: '640',
        height: '390',
        videoId: '{{ video_id }}',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

If this is not what you want you can use Ajax to get the video ID without reloading the page.